# Javascript array not reflecting pushed item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to update positions in a queue, then add to the top of the queue.  If I call two updates back to back, the loop running through the queue array is not reflecting the newly added item.

The queue is an array of objects with position properties:

```
[
 {
   position: 0,
   el:  'stuff'
 },
 {
   position: 1,
   el:  'stuff'
 },
]
```

The queue is a property in a class.  Here are my two methods I'm using.  One for incrementing the queue and then one for adding to it.

```
  addToQueue(el){
    this.incrementQueue().push({position:0, el:el});
    console.log(this.queue)
  }

  incrementQueue(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.queue.length; i++){

      this.queue[i].position++;
      if(this.queue[i].position >= this.getMax()){
        this.queue.splice(i,1);
      }
    }

    return this.queue;
  }
```

The entire class is here:

```
// Code goes here

class PassActive{
  constructor(options){
    this.options = options || (function(){console.warn('You need to pass in an options object'); return {};})();
    this.passers = this.options.passers || console.warn('You have not specified any elements to pass active between');
    this.max = this.options.max || 1;
    this.min = this.options.min || 0;
    this.removable = this.options.removable? true : false;
    this.queue = this.createQueue();



  }

  getMin(){
    return this.min;
  }

  getMax(){
    return this.max;
  }

  createQueue(){
    var obj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.getMax(); i++) {
      obj[i] = {
        position: i,
        el: null
      };
    }

    return obj;
  }

  isQueueFull(){
    var total = 0;

    this.queue.forEach(function(cv, ci, arr){
      if(cv.el){
        total++;
      } 
    });

    if(total >= this.max){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  addToQueue(el){
    this.incrementQueue().push({position:0, el:el});
    console.log(this.queue)
  }

  incrementQueue(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.queue.length; i++){

      this.queue[i].position++;
      if(this.queue[i].position >= this.getMax()){
        this.queue.splice(i,1);
      }
    }

    return this.queue;
  }

  setActive(el){
    if(el.classList.contains('active')){
      if(this.removable) {
        el.classList.remove('active');
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } else {
      el.classList.add('active');
    }
  }

}

var ops = {
  passers:   [
              document.getElementById('0'),
              document.getElementById('1'),
              document.getElementById('2'),
              document.getElementById('3'),
              document.getElementById('4'),
              document.getElementById('5')
              ],
  max: 3,
  min: 1,
  removable: false
};



var t = new PassActive(ops);
console.log(t);


t.addToQueue('Tom');
t.addToQueue('Maureen');
```

There is a [plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kXYyc3NBUpS5YZ8ttygd?p=preview)

Is the array.push method asynchronous? I may be missing something simple here.

Thanks

Comment: ?? Your code is calling `.concat()`, not `.push()`

Comment: @Pointy noted.  Fixed.  Still having the issue.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Well `.concat()` and `.push()` do *very* different things; that *must* have changed the behavior.

Comment: @Pointy if you look at the code now, you'll see I'm returning the same array and in the increment method and then pushing to it in the add method.  I still get the same issue where the second loop does not account for the pushed value after the first loop.

Comment: one problem is the `splice` in the loop. lets say on item with index 4, you splice that, this means your old item @ 5 is not @ 4. but your loop counter jumps to 5 after 4, so you won't check the item at now 4 (previously 5). you could do `i--` in your if statement

Comment: That was the answer.  Could you post that as an answer and not a comment?  It's a great catch.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is the `splice` call in the loop. lets say on item with index 4, you splice that, this means your old item @ 5 is now @ index 4. but your loop counter jumps to 5 after 4, so you won't check the item at now index 4 (previously 5). you could do `i--` in your if statement

Comment: thanx James. I'll fix that.